# How to get a simple heightmap

Tags: arcmap

I am new to using ArcMap and I'm trying to get a simple greyscale/monochrome heightmap.

How would I go about doing this?

Right now, the only thing I really managed to do is to find the topo maps

[image: topo maps]

I've read the instructions on how to remove the labels/overlay, but it mentions turning off the layer with the labels, which I don't actually get, when I save the map.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  You mention you are using ArcMap however your screenshot shows ArcGIS Online.  Can you please [edit] your question to clarify which you are actually using, and also which instructions you are following?

Answer (score 1):

To clarify your request, you appear to be using ArcGIS Online (a web application), not ArcMap (a desktop application).

With that, you'd likely want a "[Digital Elevation Model](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/displaying-a-dem-with-hillshading.htm)" (DEM) with hillshade already applied and available as a service. This gives that monochromatic feel that you are seeking, and doesn't require desktop processing on your end.

There are a variety of pre-processed hillshades out there, with a variety of scales. One is provided by the USGS, [here](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/usgs-hill-shade-base-map-service-from-the-national-map). Others can be found by searching for "Hillshade URL services" and alike. Just add the URL as a layer in AGOL.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for pre-existing digital elevation model (DEM) layers available in ArcGIS Online by clicking "Add > Search for Layers" at the top of the Map Viewer page. In the menu that appears, type a keyword (DEM, elevation, topographic, etc) and select "In: ArcGIS Online" from the dropdown menu. You can click on the titles of the results that appear to see a small preview image and click 'Add to Map' when you find one you like.

[image]

Also, if you'd like to remove the automatic basemap labels, go to "Details" then expand whatever basemap you currently have added by clicking the black arrow beside it. Removing the 'World Reference' (or something with a similar name, depending on your basemap) will make the labels disappear.

[image]